# FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector, Version=2.2.0.0,

Tags: c#, .net, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are seeing the following error repeatedly while trying to instantiate an assembly that references the CRM SDK :

FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector, Version=2.2.0.0,

We checked and the assembly in the file system has version 2.2.0.755 but in VS the properties of the reference shows 2.2.0.0. I used ILSpy to look inside the failing outer assembly and it is in fact referencing version 2.2.0.0. At first I though I'd found the problem, removed the reference and added it back again using the newer version but it resulted in the same scenario, VS shows the version of the newly added reference as 2.2.0.0. 
Is the last version number not relevant in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the location of that DLL? Is it in the same folder as the program's execution path?

Comment: You should also check your app config, to see if there is any assembly bindings defined.

Comment: Did you use a nuget package to install the dynamcis references?